# How to create interconnected schemas in MongoDB with Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am creating an web app for users to store their daily expenses. The app is in NodeJS and using Express. The schema for collecting users and users' data is as follows:

```
const dataSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email:String,
  date:String,
  amount: Number
})
 

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: String,
  password: String,
  data: {dataSchema}
})
const User = new mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
const UserData = new mongoose.model("UserData", dataSchema);
```

What I want to do is to connect  `dataSchema` to `userSchema`.

I wish to create a new `dataSchema` for each different day for every User. I wish to connect these Schemas so that `userData` can be seen in a consolidated form and not be scattered around in the data base for different users.
Is it possible to do so because currently no data is shown in "data" field
[image: Pic From DB of userSchema]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a relation between `userSchema` and `dataSchema`. You can set it up this way:

```js
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const userSchema = new Schema({
  email: String,
  password: String,
  data: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "UserData",
    },
})
```

Now you can use population. I suggest you to read [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) on the official documentation, but here is an overview:

1. Create and connect:

```
 // create a userData
 const userData = new UserData({email: "data@data.com", date: "some date", amount : 3});
 // create a user and make connection
 const user = new User({email: "me@you.he", password : "me", data: userData._id})
```

2. Query a user with his data:

```
const user = await User.findOne({ email: 'me@you.he' }).populate('userData');
```