# Mongoose population problem, how to populate another document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

How to populate comment's (postedBy, votes, replies) on get req of the feature. Each feature has comments and Each comment has postedBy, replies, votes

## my feature controller for getting single Feature

> ```
> exports.getSingleFeature = (req, res) => {
> try {
> const { slug } = req.params;
> Feature.findOne({ slug: slug.toLowerCase() })
>       .populate("postedBy", " email _id username")
>       .populate("comments", "content postedBy votes replies")
>       .populate("comments.postedBy", "_id email username")
>       .populate("postedBy", "_id email username")
>
>       .populate("")
>       .exec((err, feature) => {
> if (err) {
> return res.status(400).json({
> error: errorHandler(err),
>
>
> return res.json(feature);
>
> catch (error) {
> return res.status(400).json({
> error: error,
>
>
> };
> ```

## My comment controller-

> ```
> exports.createComment = (req, res) => {
> const { featureId } = req.params;
> const { content } = req.body;
> const postedBy = req.auth._id;
> if (!content) {
> return res
>       .status(400)
>       .send({ error: "Please provide a content with your comment." });
>   }
> const comment = new Comment({
> content,
> postedBy,
>   });
> comment.save((err, result) => {
> if (err) {
> return res.status(400).json({
> error: errorHandler(err),
>       });
>     }
> Feature.findByIdAndUpdate(
> featureId,
>       { $push: { comments: result } },
> new: true }
>     ).exec((err, result) => {
> if (err) {
> return res.json({
> error: errorHandler(err),
>         });
>       }
>     });
> return res.status(201).json(result);
>   });
> };
> ```

## My Feature Model -

> ```
> const mongoose = require("mongoose");
> const { ObjectId } = mongoose.Schema;
> const featureSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
>
> title: {
> type: String,
> required: true,
> min: 5,
> max: 40,
> trim: true,
> unique: true,
>
> type: {
> type: String,
> trim: true,
>
> description: {
> type: String,
> required: true,
> min: 25,
> max: 400,
> trim: true,
>
> slug: {
> type: String,
> unique: true,
> index: true,
>
> excerpt: {
> type: String,
> required: true,
> min: 10,
> max: 120,
> trim: true,
>
> postedBy: {
> type: ObjectId,
> ref: "User",
>
> comments: [
>
> type: ObjectId,
> ref: "Comment",
>
>
> likes: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: "User", required: true }],
>
> timestamps: true }
>
>
> module.exports = mongoose.model("Feature", featureSchema);
> ```

## MY comment Model-

> ````
> const mongoose = require("mongoose");
> const { ObjectId } = mongoose.Schema;
>
> const commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
>   {
> content: {
> type: String,
> required: true,
> trim: true,
> max: 200,
>     },
> postedBy: {
> type: ObjectId,
> ref: "User",
> required: true,
>     },
> votes: [
>       {
> postedBy: {
> type: ObjectId,
> ref: "User",
>         },
> created: {
> type: Date,
> default: Date.now,
>         },
>       },
>     ],
> replies: [
>       {
> content: {
> type: String,
> required: true,
> trim: true,
> max: 200,
>         },
> postedBy: {
> type: ObjectId,
> ref: "User",
>         },
> created: {
> type: Date,
> default: Date.now,
>         },
> votes: [
>           {
> postedBy: {
> type: ObjectId,
> ref: "User",
>             },
> created: {
> type: Date,
> default: Date.now,
>             },
>           },
>         ],
>       },
>     ],
>   },
> timestamps: true }
> );
>
> module.exports = mongoose.model("Comment", commentSchema);```
> ````

## I am getting this on postman -

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sh8MX.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create interconnected schemas in MongoDB with Mongoose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71168729/how-to-create-interconnected-schemas-in-mongodb-with-mongoose)

Comment: No, as you can see on the image of postman
I have connected comment schema with feature Schema and populating commentSchema on getting featureSchema 
what i want is to get userSchema as well
but not able  to populate user Schema that is postedBy(on  comments Schema).